# Convert from wide to long format by matching column suffixes in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have the following data:

```
dat <- read.table(text="pairing feelings_pre feelings_post ingroup_pre ingroup_post
0 22.0 22.6 66.3 67.5
1 22.0 28.5 63.2 64.6", header=T)
```

I am trying to transform this data from wide format to long so that I can plot pre and post scores as a line chart in ggplot.  So I need a column that is "pre", that is set to 1 if the column of interest has the "_pre" suffix, and set to 0 if the column has a "_post" suffix.

The partial example of the resulting dataframe would look like:

```
dat <- read.table(text="pairing variable value pre
0 feelings_pre 22.0 1
0 feelings_post 22.6 0
0 ingroup_pre 66.3 1
0 ingrop_post 67.5 0", header=T)
```

I have been trying to use `spread` and `separate` with a regex matcher, but have not been able to get it to work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% filter(pairing == 0) %>%
  gather(variable, value, -pairing) %>%
  mutate(pre = +(grepl("_pre", variable)))
```

Output:

```
  pairing      variable value pre
1       0  feelings_pre  22.0   1
2       0 feelings_post  22.6   0
3       0   ingroup_pre  66.3   1
4       0  ingroup_post  67.5   0
```

Note that this is if you'd like to filter out 0 `pairing` (as you don't have it in your example).

However, since you said this is partial, you'd just leave the `filter` part out and get also the results for `pairing` where it is equal to 1.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much.   Can you explain what the "plus" sign does in front of grepl?  Does it just convert a truth value to a numeric?

Comment: It turns `TRUE` or `FALSE` to `1` or `0`, respectively. Could also do `as.integer`, same effect. You're welcome! Consider accepting if it helped.

Comment: Thanks! (I'm just waiting for the time limit to be up to accept... t minus four minutes)

Answer (score 1):

A bit different possibility could be:

```
dat %>%
 gather(variable, value, -pairing) %>%
 mutate(pre = ifelse(sub(".*_", "", variable) == "pre", 1, 0)) 

  pairing      variable value pre
1       0  feelings_pre  22.0   1
2       1  feelings_pre  22.0   1
3       0 feelings_post  22.6   0
4       1 feelings_post  28.5   0
5       0   ingroup_pre  66.3   1
6       1   ingroup_pre  63.2   1
7       0  ingroup_post  67.5   0
8       1  ingroup_post  64.6   0
```

In this case it transforms the data from wide to long and then checks whether the part after `_` in key (i.e. "variable") is "pre". If so, it assigns 1, otherwise 0.

Or using `str_detect()` from `stringr`:

```
dat %>%
 gather(variable, value, -pairing) %>%
 mutate(pre = str_detect(variable, "_pre") * 1)
```